# Take the values of a text input and store them into an array

Tags: javascript

My code can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHC2UOT0RQX6 
The program accepts an array `var array=[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]` and solves the pseudoternary encoding scheme. All i want to do is simple. Insead of changing the elements of the array(when i want to insert a different input), i want to use the **input text** and take the **values** from  it and when i press enter or the submit button, it will solve the problem depending on the user inputs. Is that possible to take the values of the text input and make them act as an array ?
Here is the script below but it is better to see the whole code, use the link above.

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
     var array=[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]; //input here 
     var text="";
     for(var b=0;b<array.length;b++)
{ 
     text+=array[b];        
   }
       document.getElementById('enc').innerHTML=text;


        pseudo(array);   

function pseudo(a) //function pseudo
{
    var pulse = false;

    var count = 0;

    for(var b=0;b<array.length;b++)

        if(a[b]===1)
        {
        count++;

       document.write('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/30DU9iC.png">');
        }
        else if(a[b]===0)
        {
          count++;
         pulse=!pulse; //toggles boolean value each time it finds zero

        if(pulse===true) //pulse shows up
            {

      document.write('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ghtajy7.png">');


            }
            else{

                document.write('<img class="down" src="http://i.imgur.com/uObQjTA.png">');


            }
        }

}

        </script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: maybe, can you help me how to implement it?

Comment: If interpret Question correctly, why can you not use `array`? What is requirement?

Comment: because i want to take each number one by one to solve the problem, it is not just a number,i check each of the elements.

Comment: You want to get `document.getElementById('enc').innerHTML` and create an array from the `.innerHTML`?

Comment: no. I want to take inputs from the user (using the input text) and solve this problem, at this time in order to change the inputs i have to change the elements of the array.

Comment: Note, `<input>` element is self-closing and is not a valid  child element of `<head>` element.  Also, `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130281/discussion-between-csandreas1-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you want to write your code inside a function and call the function onload and onclick respectively. Try this, http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FALV2XZQ7V36

```js
var array = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; //input here 
var text = "";

function loading() {

  for (var b = 0; b < array.length; b++) {
    text += array[b];
  }
  document.getElementById('enc').innerHTML = text;


  pseudo(array);
}

function pseudo(a) //function pseudo
  {
    var pulse = false;

    var count = 0;
    var output = '';
    var b = 0;
    for (b = 0; b < a.length; b++)

      if (a[b] === 1) {
        count++;
        //document.write('<p class="w3-center w3-text-red">'+'Step '+count+': No line'+'<br>'+'</p>');
        //document.write('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/30DU9iC.png">');
        output += '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/30DU9iC.png">';
      } else if (a[b] === 0) {
      count++;
      pulse = !pulse; //toggles boolean value each time it finds zero

      if (pulse === true) //pulse shows up
      {
        //document.write('<p class="w3-center  w3-text-red">'+'Step: '+count+' goes up'+'<br>'+'</p>');
        //document.write('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ghtajy7.png">');
        output += '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ghtajy7.png">';


      } else {
        // document.write('<p class="w3-center  w3-text-red">'+'Step: '+count+' goes down'+'<br>'+'</p>');
        //document.write('<img class="down" src="http://i.imgur.com/uObQjTA.png">');
        output += '<img class="down" src="http://i.imgur.com/uObQjTA.png">';


      }

    }
    document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = output;

  }

function gettext() {

  var inputText = document.getElementById("tf").value;
  var inparray = [inputText.length];
  for (i in inputText) {
    inparray[i] = parseInt(inputText[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('enc').innerHTML = inputText;
  pseudo(inparray);
}
```

```css
body {} .pad {
  padding-top: 20%;
}
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
.down {
  margin: 0 -2 -65 -3;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>



  <title>Pseudoternary Encoding</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>-->

  <h4>Use this input </h4>
  <input type="text" id="tf"></input>
  <input type="button" style="width:50px;" value="solve" onclick="gettext()" id="tf"></input>

</head>

<body onload="loading()" ;>
  <h1>Illustration of pseudoternary encoding scheme </h1>

  <h1 class="pad w3-center">Encode <span id="enc" class="w3-text-red"> </span></h1>

  <div id="js" class="w3-center">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice, why the style of the down image isn't working?

Comment: i have updated the link please check there , css is working in that link

Comment: Note, `id` of element in` document` should be unique.

Comment: yep i knew about it maybe i forgot to change that

Comment: @vijay can you explain your getText() function a bit please? I need to understand it. Your for loop is different that the usual

Comment: For(i in inputText) in this i fetch the index value from a string inputText one by one

Answer (score 2):

Note, `<input>` element is self-closing. `<input>` element should be child nodes of `<body>` element instead of `<head>` element. `id` of element in `document` should be unique. Replace duplicate `"tf"` `id` at `input` elements with unique values. Remove `<script>` element from being child node of `div` element. Place `<script>` element before closing `</body>` tag. Substitute concatenating `.innerHTML` for `document.write()`

Attach `click` event to `input type="button"`, use `String.prototype.split()` with parameter `""` to create an array from `input type="text"` `.value`, `Array.prototype.map()` with parameter `Number` to convert `String` to `Number` values. Assign resulting array to `array` variable. Set `#js` `.innerHTML` to empty string before calling function again with `array` as parameter.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <style>
    body {}
    
    .pad {
      padding-top: 20%;
    }
    
    .inline {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .down {
      margin: 0 -2 -65 -3;
    }
  </style>

  <title>Pseudoternary Encoding</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />



</head>

<body>
  <h4 style="margin-top:240px;position:absolute">Use this input </h4>

  <h1>Illustration of pseudoternary encoding scheme </h1>
  <input type="text" style="position:relative" id="tf">
  <input type="button" style="position:relative;width:50px;" value="solve" id="button">

  <h1 class="pad w3-center">Encode <span id="enc" class="w3-text-red"> </span></h1>



  <div id="js" class="w3-center"> </div>
  <script>
    var array = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; //input here 
    var text = "";
    var enc = document.getElementById("enc");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var tf = document.getElementById("tf");
    var center = document.getElementById("js");
    for (var b = 0; b < array.length; b++) {
      text += array[b];
    }
    enc.innerHTML = text;


    pseudo(array);

    function pseudo(a) {
      var pulse = false;

      var count = 0;

      for (var b = 0; b < array.length; b++)

        if (a[b] === 1) {
        count++;
        center.innerHTML += '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/30DU9iC.png">';
      } else if (a[b] === 0) {
        count++;
        pulse = !pulse; //toggles boolean value each time it finds zero

        if (pulse === true) //pulse shows up
        {
          center.innerHTML += '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ghtajy7.png">';


        } else {
          center.innerHTML += '<img class="down" src="http://i.imgur.com/uObQjTA.png">';


        }
      }

    }

    button.onclick = function() {
      array = tf.value.split("").map(Number);
      enc.innerHTML = array.join("");
      console.log(array, enc);
      center.innerHTML = "";
      pseudo(array)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```